# Ternary operator to set values into multiple variables

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have two variables `A` and `B`, I need to set the values of both variables in one statement using a ternary operator.

eg :

```
"XYZ".equals(String 1) ? (A = String A) : ("ABC".equals(String 2) ? (B = String B) : (A = B = null)) ;
```

is this possible?

Comment: What happened when you done debugging? BTW, readability is very poor.

Comment: *"using a ternary operator i need to set the values of both these variables in one statement"* ***Why?*** As opposed to the simple, obvious `if`/`else if`/`else`? Statements like "I need to use a ternary" need explanation, as they indicate there are (odd) design constraints that the people trying to help you should be aware of.

Comment: Separately, it's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying you tried (a valid version of) the expression above and it didn't work? If not, what error did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should assign the result of the expression to some variable:

```
String value = "XYZ".equals("something") ? (A = "aValue") : ("ABC".equals("somethingElse") ? (B = "bValue") : (A = B = null));
```

It doesn't look very readable though.

Comment: This looks innovative but I will not write code like this to help my teammate :)